# UICollectionView cell layout not correct

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm very new to `UICollectionViews`. I'm making a `universal app`. What I want is that on the iPad there are 2 cells on each row. But on the iPhone there is only one cell on each row. I was able to get the iPad version set correctly. But I can't get my head around the iPhone settings.

Here are the settings so far. And has you can see on my `storyboard` it looks oké. But when I run it I see that there are still two cells on each row.

[image]

Can someone help me with this ?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        [self.collectionView registerClass:[CVCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cvCell"];

        // Configure layout
        UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
        [flowLayout setItemSize:CGSizeMake(100, 100)];
        [flowLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal];
        [self.collectionView setCollectionViewLayout:flowLayout];


    }
    -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

        [super viewWillAppear:animated];
        deviceModel = (NSString*)[UIDevice currentDevice].model;
        NSLog(@"device is = %@",deviceModel);
    }
    -(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
        if ([deviceModel isEqualToString:@"iPhone Simulator"]) {
            return 1;
        }else
        {
            return 2;
        }
    }
    -(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
          return 3;

    }
    -(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        // Setup cell identifier
        static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cvCell";

        /* Uncomment this block to use subclass-based cells */
        CVCell *cell = (CVCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];


        if (indexPath.section == 0) {
            cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        }
        if (indexPath.section == 1) {
            cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        }
        cell.titleLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"item %ld",(long)indexPath.section];
        // Return the cell
        return cell;

    }
```

Check this code which will give you one item in iPhone cell and two item in iPad..

Comment: Is that the correct way ? You are saying that each section should only contain 1 cell? But that's not the way UICollectionviews are working ?

Comment: whatever number of download component you want in single row add it as section then it will work as per requirement.